# Prove Linear Operator $(T_{w}f)(x) = |\dot{w}|^{\frac{1}{2}} f(w(x)) $ Is Unitary

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let the inner product be given by:

$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g^{\ast}(x)dx$$

Then I want to show:

$\langle T_{w}f, T_{w}g \rangle =  \langle f,g \rangle$

So we have:

$$\langle T_{w}f, T_{w}g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\dot{w}(x)|f(w(x))g^{\ast}(w(x))dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g^{\ast}(x)dx = \langle f,g \rangle$$

Under what conditions for $w$ is this true?

From my reading, I understand that when $w$ is smooth, bounded, monotonic, and injective this holds. Or at least, that is what I see claimed everywhere. But how can I show it?

**Edit:**

I think this comes down to showing that the operator:

$(T^{-1}_{w}g)(x) = \sqrt{|\dot{w^{-1}}(x)|} g(w^{-1}(x))$

Is the adjoint. I am still stuck on this. In other words, I am having trouble showing:

$\langle T_{w}f, g \rangle = \langle f, T^{-1}_{w}g \rangle$

Comment: Can't you just do a substitution in the integral?

Comment: Carmichael561 -- I literally also just did that and got the answer for $<Tf, Tg> = <f,g>$. Good work! lol

Answer (score 0):

The answer is exceedingly simple.

**Infinite:**

$\langle T_{w}f, T_{w}g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} | \dot{w}(x)| f(w(x)) g^{*}(w(x)) dx$

Let $u = w(x)$, then $du = \dot{w}(x) dx$. When $w$ is monotonic, we have $|\dot{w}(x)| = \dot{w}(x)$

So we have:

$\langle T_{w}f, T_{w}g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u) g^{*}(u) du = \langle f, g\rangle$

**Finite Case:**

In order to get the same result, we need $w:[a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ such that $w(a) = a$ and $w(b) = b$. In this way, the limits of integration don't change, and we get the same result.